# Can a box status value (color) be reactive and conditional in Shinydashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a Shinydashboard with reactive Dygraph boxes. I successfully setup a reactive box title to display the maximum value in the dataset and I'd like to do the same for the [Status option](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html#statuses-and-colors). Here's what I've got so far:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Sites", disable = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(
    #collapsed = TRUE,
    disable = TRUE,
    sidebarMenu()
  ),
  dashboardBody(

    fluidRow(
      box(title = textOutput('dyermax'), background = "black", status = textOutput('dyerStat'), dygraphOutput("plot1", height = 173))
    )
  )
)
```

**The title works as expected but the status gives an error: status can only be "primary", "success", "info", "warning", or "danger".**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #reactivePoll code for importing CSV data (datap)

  renderTable(datap())

  #Plot1

  output$plot1 <- renderDygraph({
    dyersburgp <- xts(x = datap()$dyersburg, order.by = datap()$date)
    dyersburgf <- xts(x = datap()$dyersburg.1, order.by = datap()$date)
    dyersburgmain <- cbind(dyersburgf, dyersburgp)
    output$dyermax <- renderPrint({
      cat("Dyersburg (max:", max(dyersburgp, na.rm = TRUE),"ug/m3)")
    })
    dyersburgMx <- max(dyersburgp, na.rm = TRUE)
    output$dyerStat <- renderPrint({
    if(dyersburgMx >60)("danger" else "info")
  })
    dygraph(dyersburgmain) 
  })


     }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would prefer to use the Color option instead of the Status option, but adding "color = "red"" to the box doesn't change the color at all for some reason.

Comment: You're right, NULL is not an option, however I get the same error if I change it to "info". What do you mean about dyerstat being a broken pipe?

Comment: Oh, yeah my actual code has more dygraph lines after the %>%

Comment: I didn't catch that! My actual code was not that way, see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Background

This is actually a really good question. To my understanding, the reason `textOutput` doesn't work is that, by default, [text is rendered within an HTML `div`.](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/textOutput.html) So instead of just passing the raw string ('danger', 'info', etc.), it is rendered as raw HTML. For example, if we inspect the `textOutput` element in our browser when we run the following,

```
output$my_text <- renderText({
    'this is some text'
})

textOutput('my_text')
```

we can see it actually renders the below HTML, rather than just "this is some text".

```
<div id="my_text" class="shiny-text-output shiny-bound-output">this is some text</div>
```

Obviously this is for a very good reason, and enables us to make good-looking Shiny apps without having to worry about any HTML. But it means we have to be careful when passing outputs as arguments to UI functions.

## Solution

There may be better ways to do this, but one way would be creating the HTML yourself by using `renderUI`/`uiOutput`, and using the `HTML` function in combination with `paste0` to dynamically render out HTML string to be read directly by `uiOutput` (which is an alias for the more descriptive `htmlOutput`). This example changes the status of the box when the user changes the `numericInput` to above 60, and allows the user to change the title of the box as well. Extend this as required for your own project.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

body <-
    dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
            numericInput(
                inputId = 'status_input',
                label = 'numeric input',
                value = 50),
            textInput(
                inputId = 'box_title',
                label = 'box title',
                value = ''),
            uiOutput('my_box')
        )
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # get box status as string representing html element
    box_status <- reactive({
        if (input$status_input > 60) {
            'box-danger'
        } else {
            'box-info'
        }
    })

    # get user input for box title
    box_title <- reactive({
        input$box_title
    })

    # generate html to display reactive box
    output$my_box <- renderUI({

        status <- box_status()
        title <- box_title()

        # generate the dynamic HTML string
        HTML(paste0("
            '
            <div class=\"box box-solid ", status, "\">
            <div class=\"box-header\">
                <h3 class=\"box-title\">", title, "</h3>
            </div>
            <div class=\"box-body\">
                Box content!
            </div>
            </div>
            '"
        ))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(), dashboardSidebar(),body), server)
```